# Jquery DateTime picker diff

Tags: jquery, datetime, diff, picker

I'm using 2 inline jquery datetime pickers from http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

It works well, but how to get the difference between them in hours?

http://jsfiddle.net/ajmtj1xj/1/

Thanks a lot...

```
<input id="datetimepicker3" type="text" >
    <input id="datetimepicker2" type="text" ><br>
    Result: <input id="difference" type="text" >

jQuery('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
  format:'d.m.Y H:i',
  dayOfWeekStart:'1',
  value:'12:00',
  inline:true,
  lang:'ru'
});

jQuery('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
  format:'d.m.Y H:i',
  dayOfWeekStart:'1',
  value:'12:00',
  inline:true,
  lang:'ru'
});
```

Comment: I've tried to do it in php and I succeed, but to have a result I have to refresh the page. I don't know how to do it js...

Comment: Ideally you should at least post how you've managed it in PHP and perhaps ask how you'd translate those functions into JavaScript. The below answer should get you sorted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to change your dateformat to an ISO standard so that it can be parsed into a JavaScript date object, but this should get you there. The difference of the two `d1` and `d2` date variables is in milliseconds hence / 1000 / 60 / 60...

```js
var d1 = null;
var d2 = null;

jQuery('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
  format:'Y/m/d H:i',
  dayOfWeekStart:'1',
  value:'12:00',
  inline:true,
  lang:'ru',
    onChangeDateTime:function(dp,$input){
    d1 = new Date($input.val());
        calcDiff();
  }

});

jQuery('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
  format:'Y/m/d H:i',
  dayOfWeekStart:'1',
  value:'12:00',
  inline:true,
  lang:'ru',
    onChangeDateTime:function(dp,$input){
        d2 = new Date($input.val());
 calcDiff();
  }

});

function calcDiff(){
    if(d1 != null && d2 != null){ // We have both dates
        var dh = (d2 - d1) / 1000 / 60 / 60;
        $("#difference").val(dh);
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://p-parkas.lt/valetparking/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://p-parkas.lt/valetparking/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="datetimepicker3" type="text" >
    <input id="datetimepicker2" type="text" ><br>
    Result: <input id="difference" type="text" >
```

And an updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ajmtj1xj/2/